# Set page title in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

:)

I'm using Material Design Lite in my first React app, the layout are basically this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqBJPW

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
      <header class="mdl-layout__header">
        <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
          <!-- Title -->
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
          <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
          <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
          <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
          <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
      <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My components in react are like this:

Inside menu and header I have a "Title", this is to set page title (like document.title). But, how I can set this?

My structures of components are:

> Header+Menu
>
> > Page components

But every "Page components" has unique title. Can I set state in children (Page content) components and read em parent component (header+menu)?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  Are you rendering multiple components on the same page?  If so, why do you want each component to set the document title?

Comment: Each components have title, like "home", "about", etc.
What I need are push this title into Menu (parent component).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following the structure of your template html:

One top level "page" component which renders the mdl block:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
```

With 3 child components corresponding with __header, __drawer, and __content elements, plus child components therein as necessary.

That way "page" state such as the current menu item, the corresponding page title + heading, and the body content to render, can be tracked in a component which is concerned with the page as a whole, and the details are passed as props to the children.

Comment: That correct, I changed my container div and that solved my problem. :)